# Direct umd module import returns different result than aliased import

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite, umd, esmodules

In Vite/Vue3 app I import two identical umd.js files:
One is in `node_modules/foo/bar/dist/foobar.umd.js` (and imported with alias `@foo = node_modules/@foo`).
Second `.umd.js` file is in `<root dir>/foo/bar/dist/foobar.umd.js`.

Both paths are resolved, but when imported, the module outside of `node_modules` is not imported correctly as ES module:

```
import * as foobar1 from '@foo/bar/dist/foobar.umd' // is in node_modules/foo/bar/dist/foobar.umd.js, works
import * as foobar2 from 'foo/bar/dist/foobar.umd' // NOT recognized as ES module

console.log('foobar', foobar1, foobar2)
```

`foobar1` returns named exports (app, pinia, router), `__esModule: true` and `Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"`
`foobar2` returns only `Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"`

Where is this difference coming from?

If it's relevant, this how the alias (for the correctly imported module) is defined in `vite.config.js`:

```
resolve: {
      alias: {
        '@foo': fileURLToPath(
          new URL('./node_modules/@foo', import.meta.url)
        ),
      }
    }
```

**Edit.** Vite's dependency optimization seems to be affecting this. If I add to `vite.config.js`:

```
optimizeDeps: {
      exclude: ['@foo'],
    },
```

`foobar1` is also not returning named exports, but that doesn't help me much.

Comment: Try to add "type": "module" in your package json

Comment: @Bob It allows to shorten the paths, but doesn't help with my problem - `... from 'foo/bar'` still doesn't return named exports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in edited question, apparently Vite's `optimizeDeps` seems to be the key here.
After adding to `vite.config.js`:

```
optimizeDeps: {
      include: ['foo/bar'],
    },
```

this will import named exports correctly:

```
import * as foobar2 from 'foo/bar' // works! imports named exports
import * as foobar2 from '/foo/bar' // won't work! (even though the path itself is correct)
```

It is imperative to use the exact same path as provided to `optimizeDeps.include`.

Comment: The reason why seems to be explained here: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/5566#issuecomment-965992150